# Suppose f(a,b) = - f(b,a) and f(a+1,b) - f(a-1,b) = 2a. If f(0,1) = 1, what is the value of f(999,1000)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose $f(a,b) = - f(b,a)$ and $f(a+1,b) - f(a-1,b) = 2a$.

If $f(0,1) = 1$, what is the value of $f(999,1000)$?

Hi, I've been stuck on this problem and what I have reached so far is using the method of difference to extract out $f(999,1000)$ by getting the equation: $f(1000,b) + f(999,b) - f(1,b) - f(0,b) = 999(1000)$. Afterwhich, I would substitute $b = 1000$. Also, because $f(a,b) = - f(b,a)$  would mean that $f(a,a) = 0$ $\forall $ $a \in \Bbb Z$. However, reducing my equation after subbing $b = 1000$, I am left with $f(999,1000) = 999*1000+ f(1,1000) + f(0,1000)$. From here, I just can't seem to figure out the missing link to solving the problem.

If anyone has any advice on the solution or an insight that could help me that would be much appreciated, thanks. Also, I'm wondering whether it is possible to solve the equation using a characteristic equation since it does look to me that it is a non-homogenous second order recurrence relation, however, does anyone know how would the particular solution be solved and whether the value of b will affect the solution? Just a curious thought.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(2n,1)-f(2n-2,1) = 4n-2 \Longrightarrow f(2n,1) = 4n-2+f(2n-2,1)$$

If $g(n) = f(2n,1)$, we can determine $g(n) = 2n^2+1$. So, $g(500) = 500,001 = f(1000,1)$.

$$f(1000,1) = -f(1,1000) \Longrightarrow f(1,1000) = -500,001$$

$$f(2n+1,1000)-f(2n-1,1000) = 4n \Longrightarrow f(2n+1,1000) = 4n+f(2n-1,1000)$$

If $h(n) = f(2n+1,1000)$, we can determine $h(n) = 2n^2+2n-500001$.

Thus, so long as I did not make any dumb arithmetic errors:

$$h(499) = f(999,1000) = 2\cdot 499^2+2\cdot 499-500001 = -1001$$

---

Another solution:

$$\begin{align*}f(999,1000) & = f(1,1000)+f(999,1000)-f(1,1000) \\ & = f(1,1000)+\sum_{k=1}^{499}\left(f(2k+1,1000) - f(2k-1,1000)\right) \\ & = f(1,1000) + \sum_{k=1}^{499}2(2k) \\ & = f(1,1000) + 4\dfrac{499(500)}{2} \\ & = f(1,1000) + 499,000 \\ & = -f(1000,1) + 499,000 \\ & = -\left(f(0,1)+f(1000,1)-f(0,1)\right) + 499,000 \\ & = -\left(f(0,1)+\sum_{k=1}^{500}f(2k,1)-f(2k-2,1)\right) + 499,000 \\ & = -\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{500}2(2k-1)\right)+499,000 \\ & = -\left(1+4\dfrac{500(501)}{2}-2(500)\right) + 499,000 \\ & = -1001\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(2k+1,b)-f(2k-1,b)=f(2n+1,b)-f(1,b)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2(2k)=2n(n+1),
$$
i.e.
$$\tag{1}
f(2n+1,b)=2n(n+1)+f(1,b)
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}[f(2k,b)-f(2k-2,b)=f(2n,b)-f(0,b)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2(2k-1)2n^2,
$$
i.e
\$$\tag{2}
f(2n,b)=2n^2+f(0,b)
$$

Combining equations (1) and (2), we get
\begin{eqnarray}
f(2n+1,2m)&=&2n(n+1)+f(1,2m)\\
&=&2n(n+1)-f2m,1)\\
&=&2n(n+1)-2m^2-f(0,1)\\
&=&2n(n+1)-2m^2-1.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$\tag{3}
f(2n+1,2m)=2n(n+1)-2m^2-1
$$
Since
$$
999=2(499)+1=2n+1, \quad 1000=2(500)=2m,
$$
with $n=499$ and $m=500$,
we have

\begin{eqnarray}
f(999,1000)&=&f(2n+1,3m)\\
&=&2n(n+1)-2m^2-1\\
&=&2(499)(499+1)-2(500)^2-1\\
&=&-1,001
\end{eqnarray}